# Hash function and table implementation for over 50k entries in python

Tags: python, hash

Can anyone give a good tutorial of how to create a hash table by hashing keys to values and avoiding/dealing with collisions in python?  I have seen lots of little bits of code here and there, but I was wondering if someone could assist me.

Basically:

- Create the table
- Choose a hash function and hash the keys into the table
- Deal with collisions
- Perform lookups on said table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried customizing your object to work with the built in [dict](http://wiki.python.org/moin/DictionaryKeys) type? It IS a hash table. To customize hashing, all you need to do is make sure your key objects are [Hashable](http://docs.python.org/glossary.html#term-hashable):

```
class Foo(object)
    def __hash__(self)
         #return good (int) hash for a Foo

    def __eq__(self, other)
         #return true if self == other

    def __ne__(self, other)
         #return true if self != other
```

Now Foo can be a key for a dict

```
d = {Foo(): "value1", Foo(): "value2"}
```